# How could I get the variable fetched from a website with puppeteer and make it global?

Tags: node.js, discord.js, bots, puppeteer

I am trying to fetch some data from a webiste. All looks good, the data is fetched and I can console.log(data) succesfully. The problem is: I am trying to send an embed with discord.js with the data fetched but it says the "variable" is undefined.

here's the code

```
async function foo() {
          try {
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
            const URL = 'https://tutoriale-pe.net/rezolvari-pbinfo/'
            const PROBLEMA = `${args[0]}`
            const page = await browser.newPage()
            const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"})
            await page.goto(URL)
            await navigationPromise;
            await page.waitForSelector('input[name=s]')
            await page.type('input[name=s]', `PROBLEMA`)
            //await page.$eval('input[name=s]', el => el.value = `${PROBLEMA}`)
            await page.keyboard.press('Enter')
            await page.click('.penci-image-holder.penci-lazy')
            await page.waitForSelector('.enlighter')
            await page.click('.enlighter')
            await page.waitForSelector('.enlighter-btn-raw')
            await page.click('.enlighter-btn-raw')
     
     
            let data = await page.evaluate(() => {
             let results = []
             let contents = document.querySelectorAll('#penci-post-entry-inner')
             contents.forEach((optiune) => {
                  results.push({
                      codul: optiune.querySelector('.enlighter-raw').innerText,
                  })
             })
             return results;
         })
            console.log(data);
           //all works good for now

        const EmbedBuilder = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor('#FFD700')
            .setDescription('Ai cerut rezolvarea problemei: \`' + `${args[0]}`)
            .addFields(
              { name: 'Code', value: `${data}`, inline: true},  //the "data" is undefined
              )
              .setTimestamp()
        message.channel.send(EmbedBuilder);
        await browser.close()
          } catch(e) {
              console.log(e);
              message.channel.send('Problema \`' + `${args[0]}` + '\` nu exista.');
          }
      }

foo();
```

also, I am using puppeteer to fetch the data.

Comment: Can you include the error from console as well? I think the variable `data` should be working fine as expected.

Comment: figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

To use a variable within a function like `page.evaluate` (or where you fetch/scrape something you need to call the data that has been returned. In our exemple: "results".
ex:
in data:
codul: something random;

when using the variable:
`results[0]` will have the value of "codul" within `data.results`.